# Are there good SSH clients available?

Tags: apps

I'm wondering about picking up LG Quantum to replace my HTC Vision, but I need my phone to do one thing flawlessly - be an remote SSH terminal.

My question is, are there good SSH clients for Windows Phone 7?

I was using PuTTy on S60v3, I use ConnectBot daily on my Vision, so apps that are on similar level would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

What do you consider good? A [quick search](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/search?q=SSH) of the marketplace shows a few SSH clients that have pretty good rating.

[The SSH client](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/e8aa1299-e011-486c-9f61-3232c892b17b) currently sits at 4 stars across 66 reviews. The best part is the price - Free! There is a [pro version](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/c7638f07-7cd0-4292-954c-f7e958ebed75) for $1.99 that I think adds more features.

Comment: I did not know that I can browse Marketplace like this. Nice.

Basically, I was hoping somebody that used ConnectBot and any of WP7 SSH clients could chime in and say how they compare.

Comment: There is one review on the UK marketplace that is disturbing "It acually deserves zero (0) stars... This app is itself a keylogger. It records your every keypress and sends it somewhere in Internet. It's the perfect tool for stealing passwords. Never use it!!!"

Comment: @RowlandShaw how do you know that?

Comment: @Joe I'm only stating what that review says (from: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/e8aa1299-e011-486c-9f61-3232c892b17b)

Comment: Good idea to point it out. We can let the OP decide if he will believe it or not :)

Comment: There are only two SSH clients in the marketplace, with one having a Pro version.  I use the other one (SSH Connect) which works fine.  The developer is easy to contact and replies questions and suggestions, and I have no reason to suspect any password stealing, but I do know a good way to test it, so I'll try doing that for both clients.